# Exporting Cassandra table with DataStax Bulk Loader v1.8 complains about connection pool exhaustion

Tags: cassandra, dsbulk

I run it with these settings:

```
dsbulk unload -k keyspace -t table
  --connector.csv.delimiter "^"
  --engine.maxConcurrentQueries=4
  --connector.csv.url
  ...
```

application complains about connection pool exhaustion --> application gets timeouts on connections to cassandra.

- cassandra version 2.13
- cassandra features: 3 nodes - 64 cpu/124Gb ram on each node.

explain on settings dsbulk?

Comment: Could you add the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your cluster is getting overloaded and cannot handle the `unload` operation.

You will need to throttle DSBulk to lower the amount of requests. Here are some options you can use as starting points to limit the load on your cluster:

```
    --driver.advanced.continuous-paging.page-size 1000
    --driver.advanced.continuous-paging.max-pages 10
    --engine.maxConcurrentQueries 5
    --executor.maxPerSecond 5
    --executor.maxInFlight 5
```

For details on these options, see:

- [DSBulk Driver options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/driverOptions.html)
- [DSBulk Engine options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/engineOptions.html)
- [DSBulk Executor options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/executorOptions.html)

With these settings, it will take a little longer for the `unload` operation to complete but it will at least minimise the risk of taking down your cluster. Cheers!

Comment: User reports Cassandra 2.13, so continuous paging is not enabled. I suggest playing with -maxConcurrentQueries first.

Comment: @adutra good point. 